# Is it possible to conditionally launch Chrome with a proxy configuration on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, socks, chrome

I have a networking/routing application that has a SOCKS5 interface and a more elaborate backend to route/proxy data. Anyhow I would like for a primary windows application to be able to launch applications, at the very least Chrome, to use the SOCKS5 proxy interface but have typical applications not use it.

There may be a few ways to accomplish this (I list a few rough ideas below), but I am looking to see if there is an easier/established way to do this on windows.

Rough ideas:

- Compile/modify Chromium to support the command line '--proxy-server=' argument that the primary application can call
- Configure a systemwide SOCKS5 proxy for Windows and then use system calls to figure out what applications are making the connection and filter. The Primary application would need to signal to the proxy via another means which connections to handle.
- Configure a systemwide SOCKS5 proxy for Windows and try to filter with a PAC Script. The primary application would not be needed but i would need a special IP range or domain to indicate that the application should use the Proxy.
- Need to look into it a lot more, but ideally Windows has network namespaces that i could bind applications to

Comment: you may want to look for chrome gpo at Google as it may support that

Comment: @djdomi thank you, that looks like a lighter version of the systemwide SOCKS5 proxy and PAC script option. Lighter as it is just scoped to Chrome and not all apps.

Comment: But then imho, your question is not complety at point - Do you want to use SOCKS5 for the complete system or just for Chrome?

Comment: @djdomi I want it for chrome conditionally, not always. I want the primary application to launch chrome in a special way to make it use the SOCKS5 proxy (IE: like the previously supported ''--proxy-server='' CLI  arg). That way normal Chrome execution is unaffected.

Comment: well then a plugin for chrome would be the easiest way to solve it.